# Eclipse and Facets

Tags: eclipse, facet

In the courses java, everyone (or at least most people) seemed to have a working eclipse. They always seemed to have a working faces-config (a visual one), and autocomplete in xhtml files (for facelets). Though for autocomplete, we added *.xhtml files on JSP's.

It seems that this was a part I don't know well about eclipse, and it's fairly annoying since I don't know why. When I import a project (either Maven or existing), it always has no facets but java (and that in 1.5 not even 1.6), while it is supposed to be a webproject and have facelets & dynamic web project.

Can I change those facets? It seems to just work when I put java to 1.6, but trying to edit the dynamic web module version from 2.4 to 2.5 (it is standard on 2.4) without running into some troubles. Even after I just made a fresh maven project (with an archtype in commandline), I'm not able to change much about these facets.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Eclipse functionality is driven by project metadata. If you don't have the right metadata, the projects aren't going to behave correctly.

If you are starting from scratch and creating projects in Eclipse, make sure to place all of the metadata files in your source control system (including everything under [project]/.settings directory).

If you are using Maven to generate your Eclipse project metadata, make sure that you find the Maven plugin that knows about WTP. I don't have a reference, but I know it exists. This will ensure that when Maven generates metadata, it will have the correct metadata for web projects.

> Can I change those facets? It seems to
>   just work when I put java to 1.6, but
>   trying to edit the dynamic web module
>   version from 2.4 to 2.5 (it is
>   standard on 2.4) without running into
>   some troubles.

The way facet works is that the facet author can choose not to implement version change logic. Unfortunately the Java EE module facets (such as the dynamic web module) do not have version change implemented. Other facets like Java do support this. So your experience will vary from facet to facet.

If all else fails, you can edit .settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml file by hand. Make sure to do that from Eclipse or you will need to refresh the project afterwards. Just keep in mind that if you are forcing the change like that, you might need to do some manual fixes to your project content. For instance, if you change web spec level, you may need to update the deployment descriptors.

Comment: Just to say that some facets are locked and one has to Right click on the facet and choose unlock to remove the facet - see for instance : https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/635460/

Answer (score 5):

You can change project facets. You should close eclipse , then goto  .settings directory, org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml file holds all facets related info. You can add or remove a project facet .

Comment: It looks like this it the only way to make it work if you have already created a project of a certain type  and when selecting an additional facet is not available.

Answer (score 4):

for eclipse

`Right click on the projec`t and choose `properties` from the appearing menu

There is a list in the left side of the opening window.
Select `project facets` and you will see all available facets you can choose and adjust their settings.

Comment: what version is this available at? I am on a project where we are stuck at Eclipse 3.5.2, and I don't see "facets" or "project facets" in my project properties.

Comment: can't recall the version now but it should be there for a long time.

Comment: Mine is Eclipse IDE for Java Developers Version: 2020-09 (4.17.0).
When I try right click on the project, the menu project facets does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

I recently upgraded an old project to Java8/Eclipse 4.6.1, and also ran into a facet version issue. In order to get the menu mentioned by @fmucar (which was not available in the *Eclipse for RCP and RAP Developers* package I had installed), I had to do *Install New Software* from the *Help* Menu , and select to add *Faceted Project Framework*.  I was then able to pick the facet version from the IDE.

Comment: Since this question is several years old, it might be useful to include something like "update for eclipse version x.y" to indicate that your solution is not based on the original post's assumptions

Comment: Edited my answer to give more context.